# Iterator over 2d vector class member

Tags: c++, iterator, 2d-vector

I have a 2d vector which is a class member.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myvec;
```

is there anyway that I can have a single iterator that iterates over the whole rows and columns as a public class member? then I can use it to get elements from vector.

like if the vector has 3 rows and 4 columns, I can access the 5 element which is `myvec[1][1]` by using this `iterator+5` ?

And also, is this somehow similar to `GetEnumerator()` in `IEnumerable` in C# ?
Thanks

Comment: you can use C style indexes. Since memory is allocated continuously for vectors

Comment: @yadhu not for nested vectors.

Comment: `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` also cannot be accessed with similar method AFAIK.

Comment: @appleapple I think they can, like here: 
        `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {      
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var block in _list)
                foreach (var e in block)
                    if (i++ < Count)
                        yield return e;
                    else
                        yield break;
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }`

Comment: You could overload `operator+` for your class and use `obj + 5`

Comment: @mawahballah you could write your own custom iterator type. But it is not going to be as easy to write as making an IEnumerable in C#. Also, a good iterator for a vector should be a random access iterator which an IEnumerable is not

Comment: @mawahballah you are building a new collection(iterator). and it still doesn't support `it+5`

Comment: Considering that nested vectors do not have to be the same size, I don't see how you could simply achieve this

Comment: @KillzoneKid I reserve the same size for all the rows.

Comment: @appleapple you are right about that. that's why I was asking.

Comment: @mawahballah well, I mean your c# script cannot use `+5` either. not c++ implementation.

Comment: @appleapple yes, I know, I didn't need it in the C# script, I need it in C++ only.

Comment: @mawahballah then I think you need to remove c# part from question.

Comment: @appleapple I asked about C# just to understand the difference, I don't really need it implemented in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}};

for (auto e : ranges::view::join(v)) {
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/299b66044eccb9e3)

Comment: does this support `it+5`?

Comment: I don't think so, but for sure `std::next(it, 5)`.